# Django error: AttributeError at /link/ 'LinkForm' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, django

What i wanted to accomplish is get image and create thumbnail from url. But
I keep getting this error: **AttributeError at /link/ 'LinkForm' object has no attribute 'url'** I don't know how to fix this. PS. I'm new to django and python.

models.py

```
def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return('{}/{}').format(instance.id, filename)

class Link(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Headline", max_length=100)
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rank_score = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    url = models.URLField("URL", max_length=250, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, blank=True)
    with_votes = LinkVoteCountManager()
    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('link:link_detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug,
                                                   'pk': str(self.id)
                                                   })
def get_remote_image(self):
    if self.url and not self.image_file:
        result = urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.url)
        self.image_file.save(
                os.path.basename(self.url),
                File(open(result[0]))
                )
        self.save()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

from .models import Link, Vote
from .forms import LinkForm
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

import uuid, requests
from PIL import Image

from django.core.files import File

fixed_width = 256

get_size = lambda width, height: (fixed_width, height*fixed_width/width)

class LinkListView(ListView):
    model = Link
    queryset = Link.with_votes.all()
    paginate_by = 5

class LinkDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Link

class LinkCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Link
    form_class = LinkForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        hash = str(uuid.uuid1())
        with open("tmp_img_original_{}.png".format(hash), "wb") as f:
            res = requests.get(form.url, stream=True) #Code working until this line
            if not res.ok: raise Exception("URL'de dosya yok: 404")
            for block in res.iter_content(1024): f.write(block)

            img = Image.open(f
            width, height = img.size
            img.thumbnail(get_size(width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            img.save()

            djfile = File(f)

            form.img.save("img_tn_{}.png".format(hash), djfile, save=True)
            f.close()

        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.rank_score = 0.0
        f.submitter = self.request.user
        f.save()

        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Link
import requests

class LinkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    url = forms.URLField()
    img = forms.ImageField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Link
        exclude = ('submitter', 'rank_score')
        fields = [
            'title',
            'url',
            'description'
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the form via `form.instance`:

```
res = requests.get(form.instance.url, stream=True)
```